# run langdetect each line of file

Tags: python, loops, iteration

First of all, sorry for the very basic question, probably.

I have a text file like this:

```
Abwehr
Abzweigung
ac
Acciughe
ACDR
Aceituna
acetamidobenzoico
Aceto
Achaia
Acharuli
Achladea
Achladochori
Acipenser
```

Where I'm running this to detect the language of each line:

```
import os, sys, fileinput
from langdetect import detect

for line in fileinput.input():
    print(detect(u'line') + ": " + line),
```

but it's always printing the same lang before the text.

```
et: Abwehr
et: Abzweigung
et: ac
et: Acciughe
et: ACDR
et: Aceituna
et: acetamidobenzoico
et: Aceto
et: Achaia
et: Acharuli
et: Achladea
et: Achladochori
et: Acipenser
```

I understand that it must be always pointing to the same result (first/last?), but how do I iterate the "langdetect" part and print the corresponding lang for each line?

Comment: Use `detect(line)` not `detect('line')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing a literal `"line"` string in – you'll want to just pass in the variable line:

```
print(detect(line) + ": " + line)
```

Comment: I see, but I think I do require unicode conversion with the " u'line' " otherwise the script will spit out a lot of "UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte ... ... "

Comment: `line.decode("utf-8")` if you need to decode a binary line encoded in UTF-8.